# ¿Por qué no se aplica el "align-items: center" en divs con imágenes?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando agregar 3 imágenes y centrarlas verticalmente con `align-items: center` y no me lo toma.

Puse 3 divs con una imagen cada una y al div contenedor le puse `display: flex` y `justify-content:space-evenly` para que quede bien centrado y cuando quiero que quede centrado verticalmente no me lo toma.

Recien estoy arrancando con CSS por lo que seguro algo estoy haciendo mal pero no logro identificar qué.

```css
.box__proyects {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.box__foto img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid slateblue;
  border-radius: 8%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box__proyects">
  <div class="box__foto 1st">
    <img src="https://cdn.hobbyconsolas.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/media/image/2021/05/homer-simpson-simpson-2320891.jpg?tf=3840x">
  </div>
  <div class="box__foto 2nd">
    <img src="https://cadenaser00.epimg.net/ser/imagenes/2014/12/17/television/1418786070_064451_1418786171_noticia_normal.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box__foto 3rd">
    <img src="https://cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/prisa/V52Q6PDRIFJRHD564V6KN6ZUJQ.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: está centrado verticalmente, visualmente no ves diferencia pq a) las imagenes todas tienen el mismo alto y b) el contenedor se ajusta al máximo alto. para verlo proba poniendole un alto al contenedor onda  `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Ahhh con razon, lo hice y quedo perfecto. Muchas gracias!!